# Password on visual basic

Tags: vb.net, passwords

I put a password on my ms access which acts as a databsae on my visual basic project. i have this code that error when i try to run

Me.TblMedicineTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SampleDataSet.tblMedicine)

it says Not a valid password. i dont know how to put my password in the codes so that it can access so can anyone help me on how to put my password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Project (Visual Studio / Basic) and Click Data > Show Data Sources.. from there a window pane would pop up.  Right-click on your data source and click Configure Data Source with Wizard.  If you are prompted to "Choose Dataset Editor", just click continue with Wizard and click OK.

OR

Go to DataSet Designer and right click on your dataset and click "Configure".

Click "Previous" until you're on the window with "connection string" in it.  Click New Connection.  A window would pop up (Add Connection), from here you can try to test your connection and put a password that will make the password be automatically filled every time you run the code.  Choose the DataSourceName that you'd be using and fill in the Login Information below.  Click on "Test Connection".  If it succeeded, then you shouldn't be getting your error again this time.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 btw.  If you have any more questions, please let me know.